# Are there any modern garbage collections based on two-space/Cheney's Algorithm?

Tags: garbage-collection, programming-languages

[Wikipedia's article on Cheney's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm)

> In short, two-space garbage collection, as I understand it, uses half the heap at a time, and when that half is full, the garbage collector copies all objects in use to the unused space, and the first space becomes "unused". The time cost scales with the amount of live objects. Seems nowadays, the tri-color method (which Wikipedia says is theoretically equivalent) is used.

Are there any languages or implementations of languages that still break memory into contiguous parts, rather than, say, divide memory by how it's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is extremely common. It's typically called a stop-and-copy collector rather than Cheney's algorithm and is frequently used in hybrid garbage collectors like the one used in Java HotSpot. In that garbage collector, a stop-and-copy collector is used for new object allocations (since most objects die young) and if objects survive through enough generations, they're promoted to a different memory pool where a more traditional mark-and-sweep collector is used.

Hope this helps!